# Will notification work after restart

Tags: ios4

I am still working on my first Application and i have still not received Apple developer license. I wanted to know if localnotifications are triggered even if Iphone is restarted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of this now. It local notification resumes after restart.

Ravi Kumar Singh